# Updating v7 support jar causes class not found exception

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using Eclipse and I'm trying to update my support v7 jar.
I got an appcompat v7 as a project in my workspace which other projects reference. I tried using a v7 type (instead of an old deprecated v4 type) which was unresolved when tried to import it. I then updated my v7 jar in that appcompat libs project folder which fixed the unresolved import issue but when I try to run the project I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
```

This exception is raised on the line `super.onCreate();`.

Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you added the v4 support library to your project, as well?

Comment: I didn't have a problem with v4.. all I did was just replace the jar file with another. The appcompat libs directory includes a v4 jar as well which was untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no `android-support-v4.jar` in any of your library projects. Change them to `android-support-v13.jar`, in any. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: but the v4 jar was already there to begin with and made no problem.. why would updating a different jar that was already there affect it?

Comment: Even I had the v4 jar, and I replaced it with the v13 jar. I am not sure why it works with one and not the other.

Comment: I am facing with the same problem..tried almost everything still could not find a solution. Even tried this too but did not work